# Making CodeRushXpress-11.2.13 work with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coderush-xpress

Is it possible to make CodeRush Xpress (CodeRushXpress-11.2.13.exe) work with Visual Studio 2013 by some tweaks? I understand it is not supported for VS2013 but similar was case with VS2012 and it still worked with limited functionality. I am hoping to find some work around for this.

Comment: Did you ever track down any hints that might make this work?  Or actually installed it to test it?

Comment: @2GDave Unfortunately, I didn't find any way to make this work with CodeRush. The best option is to switch to Eclipse, which has most the CodeRush features. I was pleasantly surprise, by latest Eclipse refactoring. If you have to work with C# then you better by CodeRush.